# Kendo sortable handler with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, drag-and-drop, angular-ui-sortable

I want to use handler feature in my list which is kendo sortable.

- handler: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/sortable/handlers
- angular kendo sortable:
  https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/sortable/angular

I have left side handle to drag. This feature is available in kendo sortable for jquery but not for angular.

[image]

```
<ul kendo-sortable k-on-end="endHandler(kendoEvent)" k-placeholder="placeholder" k-hint="hint" >
            <li ng-repeat="state in protocolStateList " ng-click="stateClicker(state.Id)">
                <a class="drag">
                    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v fa-lg"></i>
                </a>
                {{state.Statename}}</span>
                <input type="text" class="ordering-value" value="{{$index + 1}}" />
                <a href="#" class="state-delete col-xs-1 " ng-click="deleteState(state)">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
k-handler="'.drag'"
```

Add the above to your kendo-sortable element to define the handler query.